# JobScheduler not repeating job

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm using a JobScheduler.setPeriodic() to repeat my JobIntentService. It works the first time but never repeats. Running on Android 7.0

ConcurrentCheck.java

```
int mdelaymilles  = 30000;
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) mActivity.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mActivity, ConcurrentCheckService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setPeriodic(mdelaymilles)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .build();
        int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Job scheduled!");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(LAST_POSITION, lastPosition);
            JobIntentService.enqueueWork(mActivity, ConcurrentCheckService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Job not scheduled");
        }
```

Comment: What is your mdelaymilles set to?

Comment: @SteveMiskovetz 30 secs. edited

Comment: Does your JobService call [jobFinished(…, false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html#jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters,%20boolean)) ?

Comment: This is a JobIntentService, not a JobService, so it doesn't call jobFinished. @SteveMiskovetz answer is correct. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269482/1959110)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The minimum period a job can be scheduled is 15 minutes. If it is set to a value less than 15 minutes, the job will use 15 minutes.

See: [MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#110) in JobInfo.

Also, see this [comment](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#122) in the code too:

> Query the minimum interval allowed for periodic scheduled jobs.
>   Attempting to declare a smaller period that this when scheduling a job
>   will result in a job that is still periodic, but will run with this
>   effective period. A recurring task with your interval will need some
>   other service, possibly the Alarm Manager will work for you.

Comment: and what is the maximum periodic interval we can set in that?

Comment: The intervalMillis parameter to setPeriodic is of type long. So I suppose 2^63 -1 is the max (whatever number in milliseconds that is), but I prefer the description, "longer than a lifetime" in this context.