# JobScheduler setPeriodic never gets called

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to use `JobScheduler` to schedule a job per 3 seconds.
I have made my `Job.Builder` ready, but still when I schedule the job, `onStartJob()` is not getting called.

I am not sure what I am missing please help me.
`JobBuilder`:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,JobSchedulerService.class);

JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0,componentName)
                    .setPeriodic(5 * 1000);

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
int id = jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());


Log.i("Service","ID is :"+id);
```

Inside `JobService`,

```
public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = Utils.JOB_SCHEDULER_WHAT;
        message.obj = jobParameters;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            JobParameters jobParameters = (JobParameters)msg.obj;
            Log.i("Service:","ServiceID:"+jobParameters.getJobId());
        }
    };
}
```

Please let me know how to get this done.

Comment: *onStartJob() is not getting called* how do you know that

Comment: I put debug over there and there is a log inside handler which is not getting printed also earlier I had a log inside the method which was not printing so I concluded

Comment: Do you have `JobSchedulerService` defined in your manifest?

Comment: Yes else it will give exception if I do not do so

Comment: Minimum periodic interval for the job scheduler is 15 minutes while you have 5 seconds. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248172/jobscheduler-not-repeating-job/48269482

Answer (score 11):

Job scheduler has a minimum of setPeridic value of 15 minutes, so if you pass in less than 15 minutes (like in your case), jobScheduler just clamps up your periodic value to 15 minutes. Consider waiting 15 minutes or use setOverrideDeadline(long). see https://catinean.com/2014/10/19/smart-background-tasks-with-jobscheduler/

Comment: Do you have any link to official Document?

Comment: One suggestion, don't hard code minimum periodic value to 15 minutes. Use JobInfo.getMinPeriodMillis() added by api_24 to retrieve it.