# Android- setPeriodic for JobScheduler won't work

Tags: android, service, android-sqlite, android-jobscheduler

I've wrote an app for creating and reminding task which uses local SqliteDatabase.
I wrote a jobScheduler service to check the device time and date with tasks on the database and if matches shows a push notification. 
What I want also is service to run in background and check the data every 5 seconds .
but when I write

builder.setPeriodic(5000);
builder.setPersisted(true);

the service stops checking data.

Here's my code

**MainActivity**

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
ImageButton plusImageBtn;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
BottomNavigationView navigation;
Toolbar toolbar;
private ComponentName mServiceComponent;
private int jobId=0;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String WORK_DURATION_KEY =
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".WORK_DURATION_KEY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    plusImageBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.plusImagBtn);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, JobSchedulerService.class);

    databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_calendar:
                            selectedFragment = new CalendarFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            selectedFragment = new ViewListContents();
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;

                }
            });
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,new  ViewListContents());
    transaction.commit();
    scheduleJob();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Start service and provide it a way to communicate with this class.
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, JobSchedulerService.class);
    startService(startServiceIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    stopService(new Intent(this,JobSchedulerService.class));
    super.onStop();
}

public void scheduleJob() {
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId++, mServiceComponent);
 //  builder.setPeriodic(5000);
   // builder.setPersisted(true);

    builder.setMinimumLatency(1000);
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(1000);

    // Extras, work duration.
    PersistableBundle extras = new PersistableBundle();
    extras.putLong("",5000);
    builder.setExtras(extras);
    // Schedule job
    Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling job");
    JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        tm.schedule(builder.build());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Scheduling job  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

**JobSchedulerService**

```
  public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {
int id;
String stringId;
String date;
String taskDate,taskTitle,taskTime,sepYear,sepMonth, 
 sepDay,convert,DeviceDate;
Cursor taskDateCursor;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
Roozh roozh;
String[] seperatedString;
int iYear,iMonth, iDay;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat,  timeFormat;
private static final String TAG = JobSchedulerService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service created");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed");   }

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
    stringId = String.valueOf(params.getJobId());
    id = params.getJobId();
    final long duration = params.getExtras().getLong(WORK_DURATION_KEY);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

            taskDateCursor=databaseHelper.getDateForNotification();
            if (taskDateCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    taskTitle=taskDateCursor.getString(taskDateCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL2));
                    taskDate=taskDateCursor.getString(taskDateCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL3));
                    taskTime=taskDateCursor.getString(taskDateCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL4));


                    roozh= new Roozh();
                    seperatedString=taskDate.split("/");
                    sepYear=  seperatedString[0];
                    sepMonth=  seperatedString[1];
                    sepDay=  seperatedString[2].trim();
                    iYear= Integer.parseInt(sepYear);
                    iMonth= Integer.parseInt(sepMonth);
                    iDay= Integer.parseInt(sepDay);
                    roozh.PersianToGregorian(iYear,iMonth,iDay);
                    convert= roozh.toString();
                    dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                    DeviceDate= dateFormat.format(new Date());
                    timeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:m",Locale.getDefault());

                    String  deviceTime=timeFormat.format(new Date());

                    RemoteViews remoteViews= new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);
                    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,taskTitle);
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,taskTime);

                    if (DeviceDate.equals(convert)  && deviceTime.equals(taskTime) ){
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.drawable_circle)
                                .setContent(remoteViews)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplication(), R.color.primaryDarkColor))
                                .setShowWhen(true)
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
                        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                    }

                    Log.i(TAG, "data " + DeviceDate+ "task" + convert+ " " + "dd" + " "+  taskTime + "dt" + "" + deviceTime);
                }while (taskDateCursor.moveToNext());
            }            }
    }, duration);
    Log.i(TAG, "on start job: " + params.getJobId());
   return true;    }

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on stop job: " + params.getJobId());
    return true;    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem is the frequency you would like to execute your job. The minimum period for a job is 15 minutes in the standard AOSP. So it probably isn't the right API for you. Alarm Manager would probably be what you want, but setting an alarm for every 5 seconds is expensive. Google has also been restricting background services more and more with each release. Just something to keep in mind.

See:
[JobScheduler not repeating job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248172/jobscheduler-not-repeating-job/48269482#48269482)

Answer (score 2):

setPeriodic(long intervalMillis) only works on devices lower than Nougat change it with this [setPeriodic (long intervalMillis, long flexMillis)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long,%20long)) for devices having android version Nougat and above.

Comment: I changed it to  builder.setPeriodic(5000,6000); on API 25, but it still doesn't work. Should I use Alarm Manager?

Comment: you can also use a alarm manager as it will save user memory and battery as well

Comment: @RishabhDhiman setPeriodic(long intervalMillis) has not been deprecated. It can be used on Nougat and above.

Comment: Also, using Alarm Manager with inexact intervals is comparable to Job Scheduler with respect to battery life. Using Alarm Manager with exact intervals will drain a battery faster.

Comment: What is the meaning of flexinterval? and how does it differ from the interval?

Answer (score 0):

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is a better option.
Tasks can be scheduled by scheduleAtFixedRate or scheduleWithFixedDelay.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#schedule

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295377/9166855

The minimum period is 15minutes!